# Auto opening my dev environment with byobu and tmux

Tags: tmux, byobu

When I launch byobu (I'm using tmux), I'd like to open 3 tabs/windows in byobu and launch these commands for each window:

1) cd ~/Dev/backend; vagrant up; vagrant ssh

2) cd ~/Dev/frontend; vagrant up; vagrant ssh

3) cd ~/Dev/docs; python docs.py

Using the `new-window` command in `windows.tmux`, I can only specify a single command, e.g. "top" works, but not "cd /folder" (no spaces allowed) Is there another way?

How else would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this with [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator).